# How does a GPU access addresses or indices greater than 32 bit from the shader?

Tags: graphics, gpu, shader, vulkan

Let's just I have a struct in a storage buffer or whatever it's called depending on your API, accessed from the shader.

```
struct SomeStructType
{
    vec4;
};
```

My storage buffer is an array of the above struct:

```
SomeStructType big_array[];
```

Since in a GPU shader you only (mostly) use 4 byte types, single-precision floats and 4-byte ints, you access arrays with an int (a 4-byte or 32-bit type), so he highest index I could access is 2^32 or roughly 4.2 billion.

If you have integer value of say 4 billion, and you want to access that array, the buffer address that the GPU needs to fetch to fetch that index of that struct/object is 4 billion * sizeof(SomeStructType), which is 4 billion * 16 = 64 billion.

Does this lead to an overflow of a 32-bit integer? How does it do this?

How can you index into a buffer from the shader at a higher index than the maximum value of a 4 byte integer?

How does something like buffer device address work given that the GPU used 32-bit types? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is drawn from a false premise.

64-bit types, of an increasing variety of kinds, have been a required feature of GPUs since OpenGL 4.0. `shaderInt64` is an optional feature of Vulkan and GLSL. If the hardware support device addresses, then it also supports whatever else is needed internally to make device addresses work in shaders.

The GPU does not *only* use 32-bit types.